# Picked node in Umbraco found on local server, but not live

Tags: umbraco7

I am in a strange situation where by I can't access the Umbraco admin panel on the live server (The server itself has Url Scanner installed which is blocking access to folders containing '.', this cannot be changed right now as the impact this will have on other applications is currently unknown).

So, my set up: local build connects to the live database, a page is set up on the live site that I can visit to republish once changes have been made. All has worked perfectly, until now.

**The Problem:**
I have a node in Umbraco that I have added a content picker to and selected a node within the website. The code for the page in question has an if statement that checks for the value and outputs code accordingly, this all works fine locally, if there's no node selected, the code is output without anchor tags.

On live, the code is output as though there is no node selected. I have published a number of times, other changes are visible. I checked the file itself, the code is identical to my local build. I checked the umbraco.config file, searched for the node in question and that shows that a node has indeed been selected. So, if the node on the live server HAS got a node selected, why is the code not currently working when the exact piece of code works locally?

This would be so much easier if I could look at Umbraco in the live instance to see what's going on but at the moment, that's out of the question.

Has anyone experienced anything similar? I understand my setup is quite strange, so I won't hold my breath, but I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 1):

May be a caching issue? Take a look here to see if clearing the cache helps: [Should I delete TEMP folder when publishing Umbraco?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16438390/should-i-delete-temp-folder-when-publishing-umbraco)

Comment: Hi, sorry, it's not clear from that whether it is indeed a good idea to just delete the cache?

Comment: My understanding is that you should be able to delete the cache without any problems - only Examine indexes should be rebuilt manually. Maybe try moving the files away from the TEMP folder to begin with? ;-) I haven't had your specific problem before, but I have solved weirdnesses like it by clearing the cache.

Comment: It's clear this issue is around the fact that I have to change the content externally and try to republish the website, as that's where I imagine the caches are causing issues. I have made an urgent request to the dev team to remove the url scanner setting. Though in the meantime I will give your suggestion a go. Thanks!

Comment: How did it go, then? :-)